# Wordpress permalink category postname error with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, permalinks

I have ran into this big problem and i just cant wrap my head around it.

My setup is like this:

**WP: 4.1**

**Permalinks set to: /%category%/%postname%/**

**And category base set to: .**

The reason for doing this is because i want the site to give me a sort of archive for multiple categories.

I have, mysite.com/onecategory and mysite.com/twocategory

Both of these works as an archive using the category.php file.

This was working fine until i tried to apply some pagination.

I have read alot and tried to fix it and i have found a solution that almost works but not quite.

With [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-pagination-fix/) (category-pagination-fix) plugin it will show page/2/ but not further. page/3/ throws an 404.

Does anyone have a solution for this, it would be much appreciated since i have spent hours trying to figure this one out!

Comment: do you want to show all post's  are searched post from all category

Comment: I want to get an archive with pagination of the category selected. The permalink structure that is there right now is the one i want. But with pagination it all falls apart.